# How to change ejabberd MUC subject

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I've tried to change MUC subject using ejabberd API but didn't work. I use Postman to work with the API

**api** : /api/change_room_option

**request body :**

```
{
   "name": "testgroup",
   "service": "conference.localhost",
   "option": "subject",
   "value": "BookNerds"
}
```

**error :** "400 Bad Request"

I've enabled change_room_option in my **ejabberd.yaml** and set **allow_change_subj** to true. Using this configuration and same request body format, I successfully change 'title' and 'description'.

**Note** : I ran another test using Adium and successfully change the subject. When I check in database, **subject** and **subject_author** have been updated. Do I need to set subject_author too in the request body? If yes - I don't think it's possible since change_room_option will only accept four parameters as stated [here](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/master/src/mod_muc_admin.erl)